# Чередование звуков и фонем

Tags: фонетика, чередования

Дорогие филологи! Студентке первокурснице жутко нужна помощь! Может быть, у кого-то найдутся старые работы/конспекты по чередованию звуков и фонем? Учусь не в профильном вузе (коррекционная педагогика), но русский у нас очень сильный по количеству заданий. В связи с приближающейся сессией времени катастрофически не хватает. Была бы невероятно признательна, если бы кто-то смог помочь конспектом/примером работы! Если конкретнее, то суть моего д/з: Нужно взять любой разворот из какой-нибудь книги русского автора и на этих двух страницах найти 4 любых слова, в которых сможешь отыскать в общей сложности минимум 20 исторических и фонетических чередований звуков и фонем.
Но я буду благодарна за любую работу, которая имеет отношение к данной теме!

Answer (score 2):

Зачем старые, когда есть новые? Вот ссылочки, там всё есть, задание лёгкое,примеров много, можно использовать и их.

[Фонетическое чредование](http://www.stud24.ru/journalism/foneticheskie-cheredovaniya-zvukov-kombinatornye-i/402697-1372062-page1.html)

[Понятие фонетического закона](http://lektsii.net/2-81101.html)

Исторические чередование гласных  е — о: несу — носит, везу —возит е—о—нуль звука—и: наберу—набор—набрать — набирать е — нуль звука: день — дня, верен —верна о — а: приготовить — приготавливать о — нуль звука: сон — сна, ложь — лжи, крепок — крепка о —нуль звука — ы: посол — послать — посылатьа (я) — м — им: жать — жму — пожимать, взять — возьму —взимать а (я) — н — им: жать — жну — пожинать, примять — примну — приминать у — о в: кую — ковать,радую — радовать у — ев: ночую — ночевать, врачую — врачевать ю — ев: плюю — плевать, горюю —горевать у — о — ы: сухой — сохнуть — засыхать и — oй бить — бой, запить — запой е — ой: петь — пой

Чередование согласных г — ж: берегу — бережешь, жемчуг —жемчужина, строгий — строже к — ч: тку —печешь, мука. — мучной, ж — ш: слух — слушать, горох — горошина, сухой — суше г — з — ж: друг — друзья— дружный к — ц — ч: лик — лицо — личный a — ж: возить — вожу, мазать — мажу, низок — ниже зг — зж(ж): визг — визжать ад—зж (ж): бороздить—борозжу е — ш: носить — ношу, плясать — пляшу д — ж: ходить— хожу, молодой — моложе т—ч: хотеть—хочу, хлопотать—хлопочу ск—ст—щ пускать—пустить—пущу,густой — гуще б — бл: любить — люблю, колебать — колеблю п — пл: купить — куплю, капать — капля в —ел: давить —давлю, ловить — ловля ф — фл: графить — графлю м — мл: сломить — сломлю, дремать —дремлю д, т — е: веду — вести, плету — плести к, г—ч: привлеку—привлечь, помогу—помочь

[Чередование звуков](http://yandex.ru/clck/jsredir?from=yandex.ru%3Bsearch%2F%3Bweb%3B%3B&text=%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5%20%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%20%D0%B8%20%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%20%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85%20%D0%B7%D0%B2%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdic.academic.ru%2Fdic.nsf%2Flingvistic%2F537%2F%25D0%25B8%25D1%2581%25D1%2582%25D0%25BE%25D1%2580%25D0%25B8%25D1%2587%25D0%25B5%25D1%2581%25D0%25BA%25D0%25B8%25D0%25B5&uuid=&state=PEtFfuTeVD5kpHnK9lio9WCnKp0DidhEr16RFjt%2Fh9mgJLbEd96kfv5bNdMYYx2qoFxyhQdHzNE%3D&data=&b64e=3&sign=0af8ac110fb503f950843d19c4f70020&keyno=0&cst=AiuY0DBWFJ5Hyx_fyvalFPA9KI5rmKu0Fi1xXKZpwxjjymXfL35phY_gCDrYkk1chZ17FCpA5Xo_BJGmmnWQw0mLg_UXxjZhW4SK1HkkgfS6KMhHkqfK6VnBNMs4r_o0iZux25qw_xDdWQMXwAAMMnH0mftVVY-ZIZ5m43pea-A5D6mbAJTnZnnAbh3QBHmKJCMsYuJ8zpU&ref=orjY4mGPRjk5boDnW0uvlrrd71vZw9kpSUTzKkTkV24DzhMcu8iQio7iX6CphsbPtEuBTNCRYQZ-8AFvMCeoWToKKqArWEYtlbJr5oMXqCWdhXOkWSNpYHjJzXccQSwUAX9QCJQ1MS9mAKUTvYhzRo-WkDUbsXkN_0l0gmTOwbbZYpLINQFXaH56fFpVlIYNAZwDoKvl3LhEGqWvZqZ2JjXs5VTl-C3_sssob3wII3IM3IcH5DBuRk-USiL--2ApPNmvKYIZR3ivS2hpE_EwkM2c1jY3J4rEWldQYQGzunXgWDEVy8v3N8Wst24dNtS7tqZZkpj2vMzfhChiA_Q3Gr5FvRCkXVo5iSwgdrvWxxImJYp8jUQElJfhMdOYLHkFGA06pgP4j2M3X52Pwbn2D2BJmKsFcxkx1wjp3KMfk2b9UgPTT3stqobJJ-NLq50nTBW_svG6EynHIwCcMoasxG-fQjBrjgCgR7NhFWc9WU-rAxWmiy6s-sVJ1hdgYA6zMqIS9WikRlODlehW3VZn7GAmfDUQJE1xmtak7704p5gfozPB-752Dme7aemS1N7cXZpj4G95dCwThSuZcuenVJLaB2D2vgum9XDPOrjnsBFzrBC0HqQPGnavwwbKCZZjuesXccQSMjgAnmAFQ1J6qU95bSJcvBsYJtPqUDDK7B4JMZotor3mb2FAu1YpHMkWf8Ps4AMYeVhXmSlHFbQkHyU7x7kHcosGVne43Myhg14qzgzZSdNhOxx5trLI5COjpgXlQSxk2OjKxi7mZ7pH9uxv074dOP8hdrGcj9Ja1xTRMWXJ98ovXOCDVAEnkWN4_YKwGpz74Cw0bIAYqyZgH42Moazn1f3F_NlU4yGOhrcE-g1lic_tpSkCfqpDZjGMqKKBJzxMhv4&l10n=ru&cts=1448204034151&mc=5.003119189773539)

Answer (score 1):

дру**г** дру**ж**ба дру**з**ья; Чередование ***г/ж/з;*** ли**к** -ли**ц**о- ли**ч**ный  (**к-ц-ч**)
Блеск -блистать - блещу - [ с]  [ ст], [щ].
Бл**и**стать[ и] блещу[ е] -
Дру**г** [**г**]-друга [**к**]   (***г/к*** чередование по глухости-звонкости) ух**о**дящий [а]-уход [***о***]   чередование **о/а**, уходящий-уход [**д'/т**] - по глухости звонкости, по твердости-мягкости